# Gradle conflict between gms.google.services and com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0

Tags: android, firebase, storage

I am using firestore db with no problems until I added:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-  
     storage:11.8.0'
```

Now I get the message:
`Error:Execution failed for task':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.`

> Please fix the version conflict either by 
>       updating the version of the google-services 
>       plugin (information about the latest version is 
>       available at 
>       https://bintray.com/android/android-
>       tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or 
>       updating the version of com.google.android.gms 
>       to 11.6.0.
>   I have tried every combination of versions in my 
>       gradle file with no success.
>       When I comment out ..storage ll.8.0 the app 
>       gradle builds.

Below is my app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath ' 
com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-
services:3.2.0'
}
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XXXXXX.XXXX"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionName "2.0"
    multiDexEnabled true //Add this
    testInstrumentationRunner 

"android.support.test.runner.
AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles 
getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    repositories {
        flatDir { dirs "libs" }
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
 }
def BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION = "8.5.1" //current 
version of butterknife
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], 
dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-
v7:26.1'
implementation 
'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-
layout:1.0.2'
implementation(name: "UGrokItApi-release", ext: 
"aar")
// support
implementation supportDependencies.appCompat
implementation supportDependencies.support
implementation supportDependencies.design
implementation supportDependencies.recyclerView
implementation supportDependencies.cardView

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-
database:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-
auth:11.6.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'   

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-
auth:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-
storage:11.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
 annotationProcessor 
'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
libraries.firebaseUIDatabase
'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-
firestore:3.1.0'
implementation 
'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 
'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 
'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-
firestore:11.6.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-
firestore:3.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-
v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-
v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-
annotations:27.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-
location:11.6.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same version in firebase and gms, try to downgrade your firebase version or to increase your gms:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase- storage:11.6.0'
```

Comment: In order to optimize your Gradle build, try to replace `compile` by `implementation`

Answer (score 0):

All you google play services dependencies need to be on the same version so since you added `com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0` you now need to update all your other google dependencies to that version

Comment: I changed the version from 11.8.0 to 11.6.0 and it worked. I appreciate the quick and accurate responses.